# How to create subscribe BehaviorSubject and return value of difference type

Tags: angular, rxjs

I created a Setting-Service, which contains 2 BehaviorSubjects as below:

```
settingNameSubject = new BehaviorSubject<SettingName>({});
SettingDataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<SettingData>({});
```

`<SettingData>` contains list of objects, each object has one `<SettingName>`.

I have to create an Setting-Name-Observable, that subscribes ONLY settingNameSubject, and return value that found in SettingDataSubject.

I used combineLastest:

```
this.SettingName$ = this.SettingNameSubject.asObservable();
this.combinedOne = combineLatest(this.SettingName$, () => {
  return this.SettingDataSubjectValue.filter(item => item.name === this.SettingName$.getValue())
});
```

Are there the different ways to solve may problems?

And if i want to subscribe both BehaviorSubject, should i use combineLatest2 ?

Comment: Are these subjects always in sync? For example, what happens when a `next` is called on `SettingName$` but not on `SettingDataSubjectValue`? If these are in sync, then you may create a single subject which returns both values.

Comment: 2 subjects always in sync. Because i have 2 screens, setting-adjustment and another screen using settings to displays chart. When chart name changed, i notify Setting-Service and setting-adjustment screen will change according to chart-name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something similar where the user selects a product on one page and the product detail on the other page changes. I do it with only one BehaviorSubject like this:

```
  private productSelectedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  // Expose the action as an observable for use by any components
  productSelectedAction$ = this.productSelectedSubject.asObservable();

   selectedProduct$ = combineLatest([
    this.products$,
    this.productSelectedAction$
  ]).pipe(
    map(([products, selectedProductId]) =>
      products.find(product => product.id === selectedProductId)
    ),
    tap(product => console.log('selectedProduct', product)),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
```

The `products$` stream contains the data:

```
  products$ = this.http.get<Product[]>(this.productsUrl)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('Products', JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
```

So I'm combining the action stream (BehaviorSubject) with a data stream (obtained via http.get)

Since the detail page subscribes to `selectedProduct$`, it is automatically updated each time an item is emitted to the `productSelectedAction$` stream.

There is no need to notify it with another BehaviorSubject.

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using switchMap is more intuitive

```
settingNameSubject.pipe(switchMap(name=>
  this.SettingDataSubject.pipe(filter(item => item.name === name))
))
```